# Make audio player seekbar clickable

Tags: android, audio

Below is the code of the seekbar for my audio player. Currently, I am able to move it along, but once I lift my finger, it returns to the original song duration again. How can I navigate to any time of the song through the seekbar?

```
//initialize seekbar
seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
seekbar.setClickable(false); //this should be set to true, correct?
```

Below is where seekbar is involved, in play button onclick

```
public void play(View view){
    mediaPlayer.start();
    finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    if(oneTimeOnly == 0){
        seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
        oneTimeOnly = 1;
    }

    seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
}
```

And it is also involved in UpdateSongTime method

```
private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                        toMinutes((long) startTime)))
        );
        seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener. This interface contains three callbacks you can use for managing your audio player:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
  // MediaPlayer.seekTo(progress)
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
  // MediaPlayer.pause() 
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
  // MediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress())
}
```

In addition, you may want to have your UpdateSongRunnable pause its updates between `onStartTrackingTouch()` and `onStopTrackingTouch()`, otherwise it will continue to try to update while you have your finger on the seekbar.

Comment: do i need to set this `seekbar.setClickable(false);` to true? at xml, i have only specified the id for the seekbar, without onclick. Do I need an onclick?

Comment: No need for an onClick, you don't need to set the seekbar.clickable to true or false, the default setting works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [OnSeekBarChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html). When you perform certain acts with the SeekBar, these interface's methods are invoked. For example you say you want to move the track playback to a certain time according to where your end-user lifts up her finger. Override the `onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar)` to (if you wish) pause the music and the `onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar)` to start the music again at the time you desire.

**Note**: The seek bar is passed as a parameter in order for you to check at what time did the user lift her finger up.